# How to download Artifactory files to exact destination?

Tags: jfrog-cli

I'm using JFrog CLI to download files from Artifactory https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli/cli-for-jfrog-artifactory#downloading-files

I tried:

```
jf rt download xaxd-virtual-ctxsdk/GraphicsFiles/front/v1/*  C:\destination\
```

Expecting `icons/1.png` and `logos/2.png` to be saved to `C:\destination\icons\1.png` and `C:\destination\logos\2.png`.

What happened was the files were saved in deeply nested folders `C:\destination\GraphicsFiles\front\v1\icons\1.png` and `C:\destination\GraphicsFiles\front\v1\logos\2.png`.

How can I download the files without inserting `GraphicsFiles\front\v1` into the destination path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
jf rt download "xaxd-virtual-ctxsdk/GraphicsFiles/front/v1/(*)" "C:\destination\{1}"
```

Thanks to https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/2220#issuecomment-1735144881